# One Partition Data Loss in External HDD - Windows 10 OS

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, data-transfer

I can't able to see the data that I have transferred on my external HDD on yesterday.

Today I have plugged my external HDD again and I got surprised, I got nothing from those I have transferred yesterday.

As you see in the following image:

[image]

Yesterday I have transferred around 200gb data properly so what wrong happened that I don't know.

Within drive property, if I check then it's showing me 222gb data so definitely something exists within the drive but at present system can't able to show this.

If someone can able to provide me some suggestions to recover my data back then it will be a great help for me.

**EDIT:**
For the recovery purpose, I have tried this option:

[image]

But didn't start with inbuilt recovery system because I don't want to take a risk without taking an opinion from the expert.

Comment: Your data is likely (partially) contained within `found.000` typically file recovery software should at least find some of your data.

Comment: I have added more data to my question so please check it.

Comment: So have you performed the repair?  Hopefully, you only copied the data (instead of cut and paste) to this drive, because it has serious problems.

Comment: No up to now, I don't have performed the repair - I thought to compare to default system repair we have some better 3rd party software to attach data back into file system. No, I have just cut and pasted the whole data :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data recovery needed with a Sector Zero problem on a HDD](https://superuser.com/questions/298357/data-recovery-needed-with-a-sector-zero-problem-on-a-hdd)

Comment: At present, I have just completely formatted my external drive and created new partitions and copied data into it but damn all things get lost :( -- Let me check your given link.

Comment: Why did you proceed to format the drive that had your valuable data? Your options are extremely limited, professional data recovery is your best option.  If the data is valuable, you should stop trying to solve the problem yourself, formatting the drive will make your data recovery more difficult.

Comment: I just want to use that drive now onwards for only backup purpose so I have formatted the drive and created the new partitions based on my current requirements.

Comment: Your drive suffered a catastrophic failure you shouldn't use that drive to store anything.  Your question makes no mention of formatting the drive.

Comment: but when I attach with the other computer it's working properly because its actually internal drive and I used this - https://www.amazon.in/QuantumZERO-QZ-AD01-Universal-Converter-Adapter/dp/B011OBMQXC/ref=sr_1_18    --- to transfer data between HDD to other HDD

Comment: Your drive suffered a catastrophic failure, any data on that HDD will be at risk, it does not sound like you are ready to accept my warning though.

Comment: No, I will not use the same HDD in the future so hardware repair is possible for this HDD or I require to throw this into the garbage.

Comment: Did you try reading the Windows event logs at the time when you shut down or disconnected the drive? Maybe it was not set up for "fast removal" and you unplugged it before all data were written. Or (I had it) the USB connection was lost (like a bad cable).

Comment: @U.Windl - it was gone all things proper, I have copied whole data and then after disconnected properly - any way you have for me to try to get data from the drive? -- I have tried other question's solution but that didn't work for me.